# Looping a series of videos

Tags: javascript, loops, video

I'm really new to javascript.
I've tried this many different ways and I can't seem to get it working. 
I have 4 really short videos that I want to loop one right after the other. Basically as soon as the video ends the next video will begin (they're a set of animations that work off of the previous animation). I've tried a lot of different methods and can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone know how I would do this?

I found this

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-play-multiple-videos-in-a-loop-using-HTML5-and-JavaScript-1799.php

which is essentially what i want to do but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Edit: I managed to do it using this method. There must be an eaiser way though

```
var myVideo = _V_("myvideoplayer");
var banners = new Array("banner1_mov","banner2_mov","banner3_mov","banner4_mov");
var count = 0

function onComplete(){
    count++;
    var myVideo1 = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var videoPlaying = myVideo1.currentSrc;
    var ext = videoPlaying.substr(videoPlaying.lastIndexOf("."));
    myVideo1.width = '1140';
    myVideo1.src = "video/"+banners[count]+ext;

    myVideo.load();
    myVideo.play();
    myVideo.removeEvent("ended", onComplete);
};

myVideo.addEvent("ended", myHandler);

function myHandler() {
if(count == 3){
count = -1;
onComplete();
}
else{
onComplete();
}

       }
```

Comment: Hello, welcome. You should show the code for the things you've tried, it will help see where the problem lies. That way more people will be able to help you.

Comment: I actually ended up getting it to work with this method here but it seems like I'm back-pedalling. There must be an easier way